# How to delete an index from array in java

Tags: java, oop

I want to delete given index from array and update the array after deleting the index.Array size must be same as previous.

The task is this one

```
import java.util.*;
class Example{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int[] xr={0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(xr));//[0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90]
        delete(2, xr); //delete(int index, int[] array)
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(xr));//[0,10,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,0]

        delete(2, xr); //delete(int index, int[] array)
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(xr));//[0,10,40,50,60,70,80,90,0,0]

        delete(3, xr); //delete(int index, int[] array)
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(xr));//[0,10,40,60,70,80,90,0,0,0]
    }
}
```

I tried from this way.but i am not sure this one is correct or not.

```
import java.util.*;
class Example{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int[] xr={0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(xr));//[0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90]
        delete(2, xr); //delete(int index, int[] array)
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(xr));//[0,10,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,0]

        delete(2, xr); //delete(int index, int[] array)
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(xr));//[0,10,40,50,60,70,80,90,0,0]

        delete(3, xr); //delete(int index, int[] array)
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(xr));//[0,10,40,60,70,80,90,0,0,0]
    }

    public static void delete(int index,int[] array)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <array.length ; i++)
        {
            if (i==index)
            {
                array[i]=array[i+1];
            }
            if (i>index && i<array.length-1)
            {
                array[i]=array[i+1];
            }

        }   
        array[array.length-1]=0;    
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `delete()` method code would be very much simpler if you iterated from `index` rather than `0` and stopped at `length - 2`.

Comment: almost correct, but I believe it will fail if deleting the last position (can be simplified: see previous comment and think about the last index, also note that both `if` are doing the same operation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
public static void delete(int index,int[] array){
        if(index < 0 || index > array.length){
            return; // or throw error
        }

        for(int cpt = index; cpt < array.length - 1 ; cpt++){
            array[cpt] = array[cpt+1];
        }

        array[array.length - 1] = 0;
    }
```

It works, I hope this is what you wanted